# Use a variable value in a function name

Tags: python, python-3.x

I feel sure that I read about this somewhere but can't remember the details.
The problem I have is this:

I have two functions

```py
def go_foo():
    print("foo")

def go_bar():
    print("bar")
```

and this variable:

```py
name = "foo"
```

I want to use `name` to call one of my functions like this:

```py
go_{name}()

#output in this case would be foo
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: By using an [if](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements) statement?

Comment: @Goyo that is my current solution, I just wanted to know if there was a tighter way of coding the same thing

Comment: Sure, look at the answers. Now imagine somebody else wrote the code and you never saw it until it is given to you to fix some bug or make some chage. Would you rather see tight code or code thar is explicit and easy to understand?

Comment: @Goyo in my defense I literally had to do that on another project (hence where I heard about using variable values in function names like this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also do it using locals()

**Local symbol** table stores all information related to the local scope of the program, and is accessed in Python using `locals()` method.

```
def go_foo():
    print("foo")

def go_bar():
    print("bar")

name = "foo"

locals()['go_'+name]()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
eval('go_'+name)()
```

Many will of course tell you that this is dangerous code, prone to code injection if the value of `name` variable could be altered. The more you ignore those people, the better off your are (normally). Especially as this normally is not done in a production environment.

Comment: In either case it's still interesting to know

Comment: Is there a more production-friendly way or is this idea just an overall dangerous idea?

Comment: Introspection is considered hacking, and not recommended in production-grade services. I agree. To answer more specifically I need more info.

Comment: Just some basic knowledge about `eval`: [Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html). Use it if you must, but most often there are better solutions.

Comment: @JessicaChambers see, whaddatellya? ;]